# CMPXCHG is not atomic in this NASM program

Tags: multithreading, x86-64, nasm

I have implemented a spinlock in NASM-64 on Windows.  I'm using a spinlock to block a shared memory buffer so that each core will write to the shared buffer one core at a time in order (core 0 first, core 1 second, core 2 third, etc.)  As far as I know, a mutex or semaphore will not allow me to do the buffer writes in core order, and a spinlock is preferable because it doesn't use an OS call.

Here is the code section at issue.  This is not a complete example because the problem is in this small section of a much larger assembly program.  I used cmpxchg for atomicity.

On entry to this section, rax contains the core number and rbx contains a memory variable called spinlock_core, which is set to zero (first core) on entry to this section.  After each core is finished, spinlock_core is incremented to the next core number.

```
mov rdi,Test_Array
movq rbx,xmm11
mov [rdi+rax],rbx ; rax contains the core number offset (0, 8, 16, 24)
push rax

; Spin Lock
spin_lock_01:
lock cmpxchg [spinlock_core],rax ; spinlock_core is set to zero on first entry
jnz spin_lock_01

; To test the result:
mov rdi,Test_Array
mov [rdi+rax+32],rax
jmp out_of_here
```

The results of this test are in Test_Array, which is populated with the number of bytes to write for each core.  On return it contains:

```
40, 40, 40, 16, 0, 8, 16, 24
```

showing that cores 0-2 each have 40 bytes to write and core 3 has 16 bytes to write.  However, the last four elements of Test_Array contain the core offset for each of the four cores.  If the spinlock was working correctly (cmpxchg rax,rbx), the last four elements should all contain zero, showing that only the first core was allowed through.  But it shows that all four cores were allowed through.

I assume that my cmpxchg is not atomic, and that's why other cores leak through -- they should only be allowed in when spinlock_core is incremented to the next core, but that doesn't happen before we exit with jmp out_of_here.  According to the docs, cmpxchg should be preceded by a "lock" prefix, as in lock cmpxchg rax,rbx, but when I do that the NASM assembler says "warning:  instruction is not lockable [-w+lock]."  Felix Cloutier's site says the lock prefix is only needed if a memory operand is involved, but when I write "cmpxchg rax,[spinlock_core]" I get "invalid combination of opcodes and operands."

To summarize, my questions are:  why is cmpxchg not atomic as written above, and why does the NASM assembler not allow the use of the lock prefix?

There are a number of detailed posts on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the issue of atomicity but I haven't found any that address this specific issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you need `lock cmpxchg [mem], reg` for it to be atomic.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg.  Using it with a register destination is weird and pointless.  See [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](//stackoverflow.com/a/37246263) for a spinlock written in NASM.

Comment: Your code doesn’t ever modify spinlock_core.

Comment: @prl - the code here is not supposed to modify spinlock_core - I only want to let core 0 through.

Comment: @Peter Cordes - lock cmpxchg [spinlock_core],rax does assemble without error, but I am still getting all four cores leaking through.  I'm reading the post you referred to.

Comment: Then the rest of your code is wrong.  Your current attempt doesn't look like it makes any sense.  I'm not sure what your code is trying to do; you have a store to some address *before* taking the lock.  (And you know you can `movq [mem], xmm1` right?)  Also unclear why you'd want a qword wide spinlock.

Comment: Using cmpxchg with eax as a destination is particularly pointless, since the instruction is defined to compare eax to the destination.

Comment: @Peter Cordes - I edited the code above to use a memory location.  The code is intended to compare the core number (0, 8, 16 or 24) with the memory var "spinlock_core."  On entry spinlock_core is set to zero.  When core 0 finishes it sets spinlock_core to 8 to allow the next core through.  That part of the code is not shown here because in this section I only want to see if core 0 only is allowed through the cmpxchg instruction, but all four cores are allowed in.  I don't understand your comment "store some address before taking the lock."

Comment: Read https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg again.  It almost never makes sense to use `rax` as the source operand.  That makes it impossible to change the value of the memory location, because the store only happens if they were already equal.  i.e. all you're getting is a memory barrier and a load.  Plus leaving out parts of your locking design from the question makes it not a [mcve].

Comment: Based on your comments I am working this out.  As soon as I have an answer I will post it (likely tomorrow), or I will prepare minimal code to illustrate the problem and post that.  Thanks very much for your comments and thanks also to prl.  I am puzzled why I can't use rax because cmpxchg only exchanges the values, it does not alter them, so rax would be unchanged (am I missing something?)

Comment: I posted my solution in the original question above.  Thanks very much to both prl and Peter Cordes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this, with the help of comments below from @Peter Cordes and @prl. The changes are (1) use bx, not ax as a destination register and (2) use only the low 8-bit registers ax and bx, not rax and rbx.

```
xor rbx,rbx
spin_lock_01:
pop rax ; the core number is stored in the stack
mov bl,al ; put core number into bx
mov rcx,rax ; preserve core number for later use
push rax ; push core number back to stack
lock cmpxchg [spinlock_core],bl ; spinlock_core is set to zero on first entry
jnz spin_lock_01

; now test it
mov rdi,Test_Array
mov rbx,[spinlock_core]
mov rdx,[order_of_execution]
add rdx,1
mov [order_of_execution],rdx
mov [rdi+rcx+0],rcx
mov [rdi+rcx+32],rdx
add rbx,8
mov [spinlock_core],rbx
jmp out_of_here
```

The output in Test_Array shows as: 0,8,16,24,1,2,3,4. That shows that each of the cores is passed through in core order (1,2,3,4). The memory location spinlock_core is incremented by each core when it completes, signalling the next core.

Comment: `ax` is a 16-bit register.  Did you mean to use `al` for a single byte?  I don't see why you'd want to use 16-bit operand-size; either 8 or 32 would make sense (no extra prefixes needed).  You still have a `mov rbx, [spinlock_core]` which does a qword load.  Also, I have no idea why you'd put pop/push inside your spin-retry loop, or comment `atomic` on a reg-reg mov.  Is that left over from some debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  al and bl also work.  The single byte is atomic according to Intel.  In other references I saw ax used, which puzzled me because ax (as you said) is not a byte register.  The push and pop instructions are because the core number (I identify them as 0, 8, 16, 24) is stored on the stack because I don't have thread local storage and that's the most efficient way to store them in my experience.  I rarely access them during a program, so it adds little overhead and less overhead then a memory location.  I don't want to devote a register to that.

Comment: You're also right that the atomic comment does not belong on a reg-reg move, only a reg-mem move.

Comment: My point was that you can load the core number into another register *outside* the loop, like `movzx ecx, byte [rsp]`.  You don't need other loads/stores to the stack that the full barrier on `lock cmpxchg` has to wait for.  Or if you just want to reset AL=BL inside the loop, `mov eax,ebx`.  Obviously you reuse RCX for something else later; you don't need to dedicate one register for just a single purpose across your whole program, that would be crazy.

Comment: re: atomicity of loads/stores: any naturally-aligned load or store up to 8 bytes is atomic.  `mov [rdi], ax` is an atomic store if `rdi` is an even address.  (Actually it's atomic for cached stores if the store is contained within a single aligned qword)  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36624881).  But you need read-modify-write atomicity, so you need the `lock` prefix which makes anything atomic regardless of alignment.  But of course misaligned is much slower.)

Comment: Good point.  rcx is not used in this area so I can use rcx for that on the first pop before the spinlock.  That way I don't do it twice and not after the cmpxchg barrier.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: You're still only doing `lock cmpxchg` on the low byte of `spinlock_core`, but then doing an 8-byte load and store to it after acquiring the lock.  And there's still a load/store inside the spin-loop, not hoisted.  And you're reloading `spinlock_core` for no reason after acquiring the lock: you know what it contains because you just stored it (and have that in a register).

Comment: More importantly, you're still using `lock cmpxchg` to detect when `spinlock_core` takes a specific value.  Should be cheaper to just spin read-only on `cmp [spinlock_core], al` (with a `pause` on retry fail) without storing when you find a match!  To fully serialize the execution of your threads into a specific fixed order only needs acquire and release semantics, not a full barrier.

Comment: If you mean "mov [spinlock_core],rbx" that's because [spinlock_core] must be incremented to signal to the next core that it's ready.  But I will try now to change that to a 1 byte load/store instead.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  It should be a 1-byte store, and you already have your own core value in BL without needing `mov bl,[spinlock_core]`.  You can calculate the value you're going to store from your local core number, without looking at the spinlock (because you've decided on a fixed order that your threads have to run in).  The lock only controls how soon you can store it, when it's your thread's turn.